# Disable or enable checkbox on dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a drop-down with some entries and a checkbox.

If I've selected the 2nd entry in my drop-down, the checkbox should be enabled. Otherwise, it should be disabled and unchecked. I don't know how to deal with this.

This is what I got:

```
function checkSelected() {
    if (("#test").prop('selectedIndex') === 2) {
        //disable and uncheck
    } else {
        //enable
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<select id="test">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<input id="test2" type="checkbox" name="test2">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bind change event to `SELECT` element and the use [`.prop( propertyName, value )`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop2) to manipulate properties.

```js
$('#test').on('change', function() {
  if ($(this).prop('selectedIndex') === 2) {
    $('#test2').prop('disabled', true).prop('checked', false);
  } else {
    $('#test2').prop('disabled', false)
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="test">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<input id="test2" type="checkbox" name="test2">
```

Comment: Thanks a lot I'll try this and if it works I'll check your answer as the best ever heard ;)

Answer (score 2):

here is my solution.

First we disable the checkbox programmatically, then we watch for that value being selected and enable or disable the properties as per requirements.

Please let me know if this solves your issue!

```js
var elem = $("#test2");
elem.attr("disabled", true);
elem.change(function(){
  if($(this).val() === "saab"){
    elem.attr("disabled", false);
  }else{
    elem.attr("disabled", true);
    elem.attr('checked', false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="test">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<input id="test2" type="checkbox" name="test2">
```